# How to implement Single Sign-On in different domain applications through Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have two applications: let's say application A and application B that are running on different ports i.e. 6420 and 8000.

Theses applications are registered in the B2C tenant and are using the same 'signInUp policy'.

I am able to authenticate the user with MSAL.js (Microsoft Authentication Library).

Kindly let us know what needs to be done at code end for SSO implementation on different domain applications.

Comment: Is B2C requiring the user to log in again?

Comment: yes. I need to login again in second application while I am already logged-in first application.

Answer (score 1):

In a B2C policy, you can control the SSO experience per Policy. In the "Token, session & SSO config" part you can configure the SSO behavior:

[image]

In this section you can limit the SSO to:

- Tenant (every application in B2C)
- Application (SSO through different policies on the same app)
- Per policy
- Disabled (No SSO)

This documentation and Github sample show you how to set up the SSO:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso.md

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies

See also: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp

Comment: I have already gone through these urls that you have shared, that are theoretical documentation that are also available on Microsoft Azure docs. So Please help to me how to implement on the code end so pls share the piece of code like on Github, if it is possible that would be great help. Thanks

Comment: Is anyone has findings on my problem? if yes please share.